# use branch in multiple branches

Tags: java, git, branch

I have following situation:

I have one branch A that is holding a class in java program. This class is used in two other branches B and C developed by 2 different people. It is not finished yet, but already needed by those two people to develop their own. A is going to be finished later. How to do this so those two branches B and C are using that not finished branch A and when there are made changes to A it is possible to just pull changes from A so this class is updated in B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, the solution of your problem is simple, merging. To make changes from branch A visible in branch B do following:

```
$ git checkout A //go to branch A
$ git pull //make branch A up-to-date with origin
$ git checkout B //go to branch B
$ git pull //make branch B up-to-date with origin
$ git merge A //merge branch A into branch B
```

Now resolve conflicts, and changes from branch A are visible in branch B. This is commonly used scenario in team projects.